# Win 8.1 shutdown delayed exactly 5mins without any logs

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown

We have recently shipped 2 Win8.1 systems, and retained a 3rd one for testing purposes. Other affiliated businesses use identical hardware. Our three systems are prone to shutting down with a delay/timeout of 5mins before they actually shutdown. The affiliated businesses experience no such problem.

While that seems to point at the different drivers/services that are installed on our system, the event viewer logs show an apparently normal shutdown (including shutdown of the logging service) that is dated/timed to a few seconds after shutdown is initiated. However, the systems then continue to be powered for a further 5mins, after which they finally power off.

At times when we want to restart, the 5min delay is utterly infuriating. How could I go about determining what is causing this delay?

Comment: Are all the systems **completely identical** (hardware, software, OS version and patches)? Do you have any extra external devices attached, for example USB drives?

Comment: Hardware mostly identical - USB devices present on all systems, USB keyboards/mouses differ, but symptoms seem unrelated. Basic OS software identical too, then we add software on top - we employ different GigE network-related software with kernel-level drivers - seems most likely source of issue to us... but lost for how to log issues with it. Also, we have set our systems up for Wake-on-Lan - could be some power management settings on NIC(s) that are incorrect...

Comment: My experience is that USB external drives can cause significant sleep/hibernate shutdown delay (sometimes a lot more than 5 minutes). It appears to be related to some programs  hanging on to the disk before allowing the disk to power off. So far I've not managed to figure out which programs. :/

Comment: capture a shutdown trace with xbootmgr and share it: http://pastebin.com/RFRkuc81

Comment: I have just discovered the cause - on "identical hardware" on which I do not get the problem, I install an industrial camera driver package, and presto: the issue appears. Will consult manufacturer to see if it is a known issue and/or one with a fix. Going to ask a related question though...

Comment: [This Question](http://superuser.com/questions/938689/what-is-different-betweeen-power-off-via-power-button-and-via-menu) is related.